# Ajax on Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, ajax.net

Do you guys know about an ajax toolkit (or something similar to the m$-ajaxtoolkit) for mono??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Brian, but want to add that you should read Dave Ward's series on jQuery and ASP.net.  He really distills the essence of what you can do with jQuery, PageMethods, and WebForms without MS Ajax.  These ideas are directly applicable to the Mono / Linux environment.

Here's a list of essential posts:

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.Net Ajax PageMethods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Use FireBug To Learn jQuery](http://encosia.com/2009/09/21/updated-see-how-i-used-firebug-to-learn-jquery/)

[Simplify calling ASP.NET Services with jQuery](http://encosia.com/2009/07/21/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit works on Mono, and is open source (Ms-PL).  That doesn't preclude the use of jQuery, though.  There are actually several third party AJAX libraries and control toolkits that support Mono, and many are compatible or work in conjunction with ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend rolling your own using jQuery.  That's what m$ is doing now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Mono website

Do you remember, that you have no development environment in this machine? You can install it, or download Mono liveCD with openSuse. But before doing it, please note, that GTK# (it’s devenv) is not very user friendly. It even worse, then Eclipse. So let’s try to understand first whether we can fix small compatibility problems without entering code.

The most convenient method to debug web site on Mono is by using XSP and XSP2 mini web servers. Just enter the directory of the site and run it. By default you’ll be able to access the site by using ... (it also be written for you). Enter and notice whether you have any errors in console. No? Keep doing

The most common problem is “error 500” with nonsense stack. If it contains ScriptManager error Type not found, the problem is in Web.config file. Try to regenerate it to be compatible to Mono (for example, Mono has different version of System.Web.Extensions assembly. In ASP.NET 3.5 it has version 3.5, Mono has only 1.0.61025.0 (the old AJAX.NET). To recreate your web.config all you have to do is to execute “mconfig af AJAX Web.config” It will create default web.config file, supports System.Web.Extensions (AJAX features).

Not helped? Keep doing. Let’s look another time into the stack – if it contains errors in “EnablePageMethods” or “ShouldGenerateScript” or “EncryptString” – the problem is serialization. Mono has very limited support for JSON, XML and SOAP serialization. Try to look into your code and notice if you have classes, marked with [Serializable] or you are transferring your own classes by using PageMethods. If so, replace it with regular strings (my grandma serialization).